# Getting relational data in AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Looking at the example on this page:
http://firefeed.io/about.html

Is there a way to get and display relational data (the sparks) using AngularFire?

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to create two instances of angularFire, one to get spark IDs for the current user and another one to get the sparks themselves. For example:

```js
function MyController($scope, angularFire) {
  var url = "https://firefeed.firebaseio.com/users/" + $scope.userid + "/sparks";
  angularFire(url, $scope, 'userSparkIDs', {});
  angularFire(url, $scope, 'sparks', {});
}
```

And then you can access speak IDs via `$scope.userSparkIDs` and the actual spark contents via `$scope.sparks[sparkID]`.